# how can I load jquery Tab using URL with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

We're using jquery tabs on our website, Tabs can be seen at http://www.wirenine.com/web-hosting/

We want to be able to load a secondary tab using some sort of anchor like #faq in the URL to load the secondary tab by default on page load. How can this be achieved? Tabs JS code can be seen at

http://cdn.wirenine.com/js/tabs.js

```
    //<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function displayPage(e) {
    var current = $(this).parent().attr("data-current");
    $("#tabHeader_" + current).removeClass("tabActiveHeader")
    $("#tabpage_" + current).hide();

    var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $(this).addClass("tabActiveHeader");
    $("#tabpage_" + ident).show();
    $(this).parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident })
}
$(function() {
    var container = $("#tabContainer"),
        navitem = container.find((".tabs ul li")).first(),
        ident = navitem[0].id.split("_")[1];
    navitem.addClass("tabActiveHeader").parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident });

    $(".tabpage").filter(function(i) { return i>0; }).hide();
    // OR
    // $(".tabpage:not(:first-child)").hide();

    $(".tabs ul li").on("click", displayPage)
});
});//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var targetTab = location.hash.replace(/#/, '');
    $("li[id$='" + targetTab + "']").click();
});
```

You can replace the numerical portion of the IDs on your `tabHeader` listItems to names like `tabHeader_faqs`, `tabHeader_plans` and it should work.

Comment: That doesn't work, when I input the js into the tabs.js file and changed the tabheader IDs using #faqs or #plans in the url didn't load the tab.

Comment: You'll need to change the `tabpage_` IDs to match their respective `tabHeader_` IDs as well, since in you're code you're splitting the ID by _ and querying the relevant `tabpage` ID.

Comment: Either that, or you use #1, #2..in your URL hash instead of #faq or #plans.

Comment: Okay I forgot to reset the cdn cache :X 

How can I get it to load instantly instead of the page load delay that's there when going to http://www.wirenine.com/web-hosting/#3 ?

Comment: Is it possible to get it to load the tab in the anchor URL instead of loading the first tab? I hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: For that, you'll need a vanilla javascript implementation because jQuery works only when the DOM has fully loaded.

Comment: As a workaround, what you can do is, set #content to `display: none` and active tab to the first. Then in the jQuery code, if `location.hash` is not blank, trigger the click to the relevant tab. Show the #content div after that.

Comment: how would I achieve that exactly? is there some code for the display: none for content to be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

The checkTab function checks if the added value is in the url. If it is, Tab 5 will be shown with display: block; in css. So the tab is always on your page, but will only show if the value u added(checkTab(value)) is in the url.

### HTML

```
<li id="tabHeader_5">
    <span>faq</span>
</li>

<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_5">
    Faq
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#tabHeader_5{
    display: none;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
function displayPage(e) {

 checkTab('#faq');
 var current = $(this).parent().attr("data-current");
$("#tabHeader_" + current).removeClass("tabActiveHeader")
$("#tabpage_" + current).hide();

var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
$(this).addClass("tabActiveHeader");
$("#tabpage_" + ident).show();
$(this).parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident })
 }
 $(function() {
    var container = $("#tabContainer"),
    navitem = container.find((".tabs ul li")).first(),
    ident = navitem[0].id.split("_")[1];
    navitem.addClass("tabActiveHeader").parent().attr({ 'data-current': ident });

$(".tabpage").filter(function(i) { return i>0; }).hide();
// OR
// $(".tabpage:not(:first-child)").hide();

$(".tabs ul li").on("click", displayPage)
});
});

function checkTab(value)
{

    var tabUrl = href.toString().toLowerCase();

    if (tabUrl.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $('#tabHeader_5').show();
    }



}

//]]>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Do I just change the tabs.js with this new code and how would it work exactly? any other changes required?

Comment: I don't know anything tabs.js especially, but I think this is the easiest way to get what u want. (add a extra tab and div to the tabs div, if the value is in the url the tab will be shown) I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You could simply insert in your url GET param as:

```
http://www.wirenine.com/web-hosting/?tab=faq
```

This page must be dynamic, generated by php or asp.

Sample PHP:

```
 <li id="tabHeader_1" <?php if($_GET['tab'] == 'plans') echo 'class="tabActiveHeader"'; ?> ><span>Plans &amp; Features</span></li>
        <li id="tabHeader_2" <?php if($_GET['tab'] == 'compare') echo 'class="tabActiveHeader"'; ?>><span>Compare All Plans</span></li>
        <li id="tabHeader_3" <?php if($_GET['tab'] == 'faq') echo 'class="tabActiveHeader"'; ?>><span>FAQ's</span></li>
        <li id="tabHeader_4" <?php if($_GET['tab'] == 'competition') echo 'class="tabActiveHeader"'; ?>><span>WireNine vs The Competition</span></li>
```

I think you got the idea.